# Protection from accidentally misnaming object attributes in Python?

Tags: python, attributes

A friend was "burned" when starting to learn Python, and now sees the language as <strike>perhaps fatally</strike> flawed.

He was using a library and changed the value of an object's attribute (the class being in the library), but he used the wrong abbreviation for the attribute name.  It took him "forever" to figure out what was wrong.  His objection to Python is thus that it allows one to accidentally add attributes to an object.

Unit tests don't provide a solution to this.  One doesn't write unit tests against an API being used.  One may have a mock for the class, but the mock could have the same typo or incorrect assumption about the attribute name.

It's possible to use `__setattr__()` to guard against this, but (as far as I know), no one does.

The only thing I've been able to tell my friend is that after several years of writing Python code full-time,  I don't recall ever being burned by this.  What else can I tell him?

Comment: This is not a "hypothetical" friend.  :-)

Comment: My friend has corrected me.  He agrees that all languages have benefits and flaws.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"changed the value of an object's attribute"  Can lead to problems.  This is pretty well known.  You know it, now, also.  That doesn't indict the language.  It simply says that you've learned an important lesson in dynamic language programming.

1. Unit testing absolutely discovers this.  You are not forced to mock all library classes.  Some folks say it's only a unit test when it's tested in complete isolation. This is silly.  You have to trust the library modules -- it's a feature of your architecture.  Rather than mock them, just use them.   (It is important to write mocks for your own newly-developed libraries.  It's also important to mock libraries that make expensive API calls.)

   In most cases, you can (and should) test your classes with the *real* library modules.  This will find the misspelled attribute name.
2. Also, now that you know that attributes are dynamic, it's really easy to verify that the attribute exists.  How?

   Use interactive Python to explore the classes before writing too much code.

   Remember, Python is not Java and it's not C.  You can execute Python interactively and determine immediately if you've spelled something wrong.  Writing a lot of code without doing any interactive confirmation is -- simply -- the wrong way to use Python.

   A little interactive exploration will find misspelled attribute names.
3. Finally -- for your own classes -- you can wrap updatable attributes as properties.  This makes it easier to debug any misspelled attribute names.  Again, you know to check for this.  You can use interactive development to confirm the attribute names.

Fussing around with `__setattr__` creates problems.  In some cases, we actually need to add attributes to an object.  Why?  It's simpler than creating a whole subclass for one special case where we have to maintain more state information.

---

Other things you can say:

I was burned by a C program that absolutely could not be made to work because of `______`.  [Insert any known C-language problem you want here.  No array bounds checking, for example]  Does that make C fatally flawed?

I was burned by a DBA who changed a column name and all the SQL broke.  It's painful to unit test all of it.  Does that make the relational database fatally flawed?

I was burned by a sys admin who changed a directory's permissions and my application broke.  It was nearly impossible to find.  Does that make the OS fatally flawed?

I was burned by a COBOL program where someone changed the copybook, forgot to recompile the program, and we couldn't debug it because the source looked perfect.  COBOL, however, actually *is* fatally flawed, so this isn't a good example.

Comment: The COBOL one is such a cheap shot, I just have to give you +1 for that.

Comment: @balpha: True.  I had a load of other examples of "dynamic" structures (other than OS and RDBMS resources) that we rely on without thinking too much about them.  But I figured that three examples was enough to make the point about fatally flawed.  But the COBOL one was too funny (to me) to pass up.

Answer (score 7):

There are code analyzers like [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) that will warn you if you add a attribute outside of `__init__`. PyDev has nice support for it. Such errors are very easy to find with a debugger too.

Comment: PyDev also has autocomplete, just like Eclipse or VS or probably any other IDE your friend is familiar with. So he could try to get in the habit of just typing `self.` followed by the first letter or two of the attribute, and letting the autocomplete fill in the rest. That way you're guaranteed to spell it right.

Answer (score 5):

If the possibility to make mistakes is enough for him to consider a language "fatally flawed", I don't think you can convince him otherwise. The more you can do with a language, the more you can do *wrong* with the language. It's a caveat of flexibility—but that's true for any language.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `__slots__` class attribute to limit the attributes that instances have. Attempting to set an attribute that's not expliticly listed will raise an `AttributeError`. There are some complications that arise with subclassing. See the [Python data model reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

A tool like [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) or [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) may be able to detect this.

Answer (score 1):

He's effectively ruling out an entire class of programming languages -- dynamically-typed languages -- because of one hard lesson learned. He can use only statically-typed languages if he wishes and still have a very productive career as a programmer, but he is certainly going to have deep frustrations with them as well. Will he then conclude that they are fatally-flawed?

Answer (score 1):

I think your friend has misplaced his frustration in the language. His real problem is lack of debugging techniques. teach him how to break down a program into small pieces to examine the output. like a manual unit test, this way any inconsistency is found and any assumptions are proven or discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bad experience with Python when I first started ... took me 3 months to get over it. Having a tool which warns would be nice back then ...